# How to get eq to effect all instances and not just the first instance?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have a class called datetimeselect on a div that contains a label and 5 selects. I want to set a custom width for each of these selects. However, the coffeescript that I wrote only effects the first div with the class and not the rest of the divs with that class. How do I get my code to effect all divs with the class datetimeselect?

my coffeescript:

```
jQuery ->

    a = [75, 110, 60, 80, 60]

    $(".datetimeselect").children('select').eq(0).css("width", a[0])

    $(".datetimeselect").children('select').eq(1).css("width", a[1])

    $(".datetimeselect").children('select').eq(2).css("width", a[2])

    $(".datetimeselect").children('select').eq(3).css("width", a[3])

    $(".datetimeselect").children('select').eq(4).css("width", a[4])
```

html/erb code:

```
<div class="well datetimeselect">
    <%= f.label :time_start, "Time Start:" %> 

    <%= f.datetime_select :time_start, ampm: true, :class => "field span1" %>
</div>

<div class="well datetimeselect">
    <%= f.label :time_end, "Time End:" %> 

    <%= f.datetime_select :time_end, default: 1.days.from_now, ampm: true, :class => "field span1" %>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't use `.eq()` at all. `$(".datetimeselect").each(...)` -> [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `.eq()` at all. Make use of [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) instead

```
$(".datetimeselect").each(function(idx, el) {
    $(el).children("select").css("width", a[idx % a.length]);
});
```

Comment: thanks for the help dude. This doesn't work, but I'm playing around with it.

Comment: the reason why this isn't working is because the idx value goes up to 9 and doesn't reset to 0 when it's 5

Comment: This condition was not perceptible from your question. I've edited my answer accordingly (`a[idx % a.length]`)

Comment: for some reason this makes the first set of selects 75 and then the next set of selects 110

Comment: I ended up making the selects' width set to auto, and that did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.css()` callback function:

```
$(".datetimeselect > select").css('width', function(ind) {
   return a[ind];
});
```

CoffeeScript:

```
$(".datetimeselect > select").css 'width', (index) -> a[index]
```

Comment: Thanks undefined, but it only works on the first instance of a div with the class of datetimeselect